# How to programmatically create a shipment from multiple orders?

Tags: acumatica

What is the easiest way to create a shipment and add multiple orders to it with all of their items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample below utilize the **CreateShipment** method used on both the Sales Orders and Shipments screens. Basically what this sample is doing is looping through all SOShipmentPlan plan for the given Customer and the given Warehouse to select them in a way similar to how the Add Sales Orders popup works on the Shipment screen. The only difference is the execution of a single BQL-query to retrieve all SOShipmentPlan records, that can be added to the Shipment, instead of manipulating with the Add Sales Orders popup thought code.

```
string operation = SOOperation.Issue;
var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
var shipment = graph.Document.Insert();
var customer = (BAccountR)PXSelect<BAccountR,
    Where<BAccountR.acctCD, Equal<Required<BAccountR.acctCD>>>>
    .SelectSingleBound(graph, new object[] { }, "ABARTENDE");
shipment.CustomerID = customer.BAccountID;
shipment = graph.Document.Update(shipment);
var warehouse = (INSite)PXSelect<INSite,
    Where<INSite.siteCD, Equal<Required<INSite.siteCD>>>>
    .SelectSingleBound(graph, new object[] { }, "RETAIL");
shipment.SiteID = warehouse.SiteID;
graph.Document.Update(shipment);

SOOrder prevOrder = null;
foreach (PXResult<SOShipmentPlan, SOLineSplit, SOOrderShipment, SOOrder> res in 
    PXSelectJoin<SOShipmentPlan,
        InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, 
            On<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.planID>>,
        LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment,
            On<SOOrderShipment.orderType, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.orderType>,
                And<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.orderNbr>,
                And<SOOrderShipment.operation, Equal<SOLineSplit.operation>,
                And<SOOrderShipment.siteID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.siteID>,
                And<SOOrderShipment.confirmed, Equal<boolFalse>,
                And<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, NotEqual<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>>>>>,
        InnerJoin<SOOrder, 
            On<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.orderType>, 
                And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.orderNbr>,
                And<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<Current<SOShipment.customerID>>,
                And<SOOrder.cancelled, Equal<boolFalse>,
                And<SOOrder.completed, Equal<boolFalse>,
                And<SOOrder.hold, Equal<False>,
                And<SOOrder.creditHold, Equal<False>>>>>>>>>>>,
        Where<SOShipmentPlan.orderType, Equal<Required<SOShipmentPlan.orderType>>,
            And<SOShipmentPlan.siteID, Equal<Current<SOShipment.siteID>>,
            And<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, IsNull,
            And<SOLineSplit.operation, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.operation>>,
            And2<
                Where<Current<SOShipment.destinationSiteID>, IsNull,
                    Or<SOShipmentPlan.destinationSiteID, Equal<Current<SOShipment.destinationSiteID>>>>,
                And<
                    Where<SOShipmentPlan.inclQtySOShipping, Equal<True>, 
                        Or<SOShipmentPlan.inclQtySOShipped, Equal<True>, 
                        Or<SOShipmentPlan.requireAllocation, Equal<False>, 
                        Or<SOLineSplit.lineType, Equal<SOLineType.nonInventory>>>>>>>>>>>>
        .Select(graph, "SO", operation))
{
    var plan = (SOShipmentPlan)res;
    plan.Selected = true;
    graph.soshipmentplan.Update(plan);

    var order = (SOOrder)res;
    prevOrder = prevOrder ?? order;
    if (order.OrderNbr == prevOrder.OrderNbr) continue;

    graph.CreateShipment(prevOrder, shipment.SiteID, shipment.ShipDate, false, operation, null);
    graph.soshipmentplan.Cache.Clear();
    prevOrder = order;
}
if (prevOrder != null)
{
    graph.CreateShipment(prevOrder, shipment.SiteID, shipment.ShipDate, false, operation, null);
    graph.soshipmentplan.Cache.Clear();
}

graph.Actions.PressSave();
```